# UNIX / Linux / Mac OSX get permission of file as number

Tags: macos, posix, file-permissions

This must be really simple to do but have completely drawn a blank.  I can see the permission of files by using ls -la which can give something like:

```
-rwxr-xr-x   1 james  staff   68  8 Feb 13:33 basic.sh*
-rw-r--r--   1 james  staff   68  8 Feb 13:33 otherFile.sh*
```

How do I translate that into a number for use with `chmod` like `chmod 755 otherFile.sh` (with out doing the manual conversion).

Comment: Just a note that may make your research easier: Mac OS X is BSD UNIX and any UNIX way of solving the problem will also do. (As will many Linux ways.)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

`stat -f "%Lp" [filename]` works for me in OS X 10.8.

Comment: Strange, the man page for `stat` in 10.7 makes it look like those options should work the way they do in 10.8. What error are you getting?

Comment: Hmmm, that's strange, I thought your answer was something like: `stat -c "%a %w" [filename]` which doesn't work.  Your answer does work though.

Comment: Note: for linux use:  `stat -c '%a' [filename]`

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use the `stat` command instead of `ls`.  From looking at the [manpage](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man1/stat.1.html), this should work to get the file permissions:

```
for f in dir/*
do
    perms=$(stat -f '0%Hp%Mp%Lp' $f)
    echo "$f has permissions $perms"
done
```

(although I am not at my Mac at the moment and therefore cannot test it).

Comment: @AJP, from further study of the manpage, I think you need to specify Hp, Mp and Lp to get all the file permissions.  Please see my edit.

Comment: yes my edit was just to show that i only wanted the `755` part so that I could use it with chmod to change the permissions for read, write and execution.  But your answer does give the full permissions.

Comment: @AJP I don't understand how both answers could be correct.  Are you saying that `stat -f '%Hp%Mp%Lp'` **and** `stat -f '%Lp'` give identical results?

Comment: no they give different results and `stat -f '%Lp'` is what I want.

Comment: @AJP Hmm, that doesn't seem to meet the requirements of your question as it only returns the user part of the file permissions; the example you show in your question has all (user, group and other) file permissions.

Comment: I wanted to be able to run `chmod NNN aFile` where NNN is the permissions of a different file.  `stat -f '%Lp' differentFile` provided 755 which is exactly what I wanted.

Comment: @AJP Oh OK; when I tested it (finally) last night `'%Lp'` gave me `005`.